# Gracefully quit "Install macOS Ventura.app" with Terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, kill

I have a script I would like to deploy to Mac endpoints which would quit the "Install macOS Ventura" installer app if it's open. I'm using the `kill -9 <PID>` command, and it doesn't quit the app completely. Instead, an error popup appears which requires user input to click OK. Once OK is clicked, the app then quits.
[image]
How can I use a command to get the app to **completely** quit without an error message, or a command to acknowledge the error popup on behalf of the user?

Also, I prefer not to use osascript if possible.

Comment: Did you checked all the possibilities are documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903076/how-to-kill-a-process-in-macos)

Comment: Yes, none of those options worked for completely killing the Installer.

Comment: Reboot the OS if the installer is already open. Is this an option for you?

Comment: No, but thank you. I can quit the installer no problem. What I'm trying to do is create a script to deploy to many Mac endpoints to automate quitting the installer so it does not require user interaction.

Comment: I know you want write script for task automation. The point is, you can replace the kill task with a reboot task.After reboot you can do anything else by knowing the installer is not running.

Comment: That is true, and a valid option. However, I do not want to force a reboot.